# Overriding UILabel text getter not working

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboards and I'd like to have some labels which always show a given emoji at the start of the label.

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CocoaLumberjack

class PITLabel: UILabel {

    override public var text: String? {
        set {
            super.text = newValue?.prependedWithGenderEmoji()
            DDLogDebug(" set super.text: \(super.text ?? "")")
        }

        get {
            let newVal = super.text?.prependedWithGenderEmoji()
            DDLogDebug(" get super.text: \(newVal ?? "")")
            return newVal
        }
    }

    override public var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        set {
            super.attributedText = newValue
            DDLogDebug(" set super.attributed: \(super.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString(string: ""))")
        }

        get {
            let genderString = super.attributedText?.string.prependedWithGenderEmoji()
            let rangePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>.allocate(capacity: 8)
            rangePointer.pointee = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
            let originalAttributes = super.attributedText?.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: rangePointer)

            let newAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: genderString!, attributes: originalAttributes)

            DDLogDebug(" get super.attributed: \(newAttributedString)")
            return newAttributedString
        }
    }

}
```

And I've set the labels to class `PITLabel` in the Storyboard.

[image]

[image]

When the app is run the following is present in the console output:

```
 get super.text: ‍♂️ PiT SETTINGS
 get super.attributed: ‍♂️ PiT SETTINGS{
NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.0352941 0.498039 0.662745 1";
    <snip>
}
```

This is as expected.

But in the UI of the app it does not show the emoji.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the setter for setting the value to the label?

Comment: That's because when setting the values from storyboard directly the `text` or `attributedText` won't get called. They will get called only when you set it programmatically

Comment: The get values do get called, you can see that from the log output. But they are not used for whatever reason. Is it. It possible to do have a label like this?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're actually not prepending it to the text. It should be:

```
override public var text: String? {
    set {
        let result = newValue.prependedWithGenderEmoji()
        super.text = result
    }

    get {
        return super.text
    }
}
```

Setting the text in Interface Builder does not call the `text` setter that you override. You have to set it in the code.

`yourPitLabel.text = "PiT SETTING`

Comment: Thanks for this. I tired it, but the setter never gets called

Comment: how do you set the `text`?

Comment: in the storyboard. I added a check for attributed string and updated the question with more details

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't mean this to be a criticism of you, but I am right in thinking there is basically no point in using a custom label for this? If I have to set the label in code I might as well just apply the .gender() function there